# Reconciling similar identifiers to make them primary keys SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Refer to the screen cap below for sample data.  normalizing these data I found these similar codes that mean the same thing as far as my data are concerned.  I'm trying to update my table so that the `primarycode`s on the right are updated to those on the left

[image]

The query I used to find these values:

```
select  *
from icd
inner join icd as i2 on i2.primarycodetext=icd.primarycodetext
and i2.primarycode <> icd.primarycode
where icd.primarycode like '%0'
```

The update query I tried.

```
update icd
set icd.primarycode=i2.primarycode
from 
(


select  *
from icd
inner join icd as i2 on i2.primarycodetext=icd.primarycodetext
and i2.primarycode <> icd.primarycode
where icd.primarycode like '%0'
)t
```

The error received: `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The column 'primarycode' was specified multiple times for 't'.`

EDIT: the only two columns in this table are primarycode and primarycodetext

Comment: But then you are gonna have duplicate records on your table, is that the result you want?

Comment: I don't understand merge well enough so I was going to select distinct after this was done into a new table to get rid of duplicates

Comment: plus, i haven't seen an example, can you `merge` with a self join?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. I *think* that you really want to delete the records with the zero at the end instead of updating them and then having duplicates, am I right?

Comment: yes, that does seem more expedient that what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for your question as it is, you should do the following:

```
UPDATE I1
SET I1.primarycode = I2.primarycode
FROM icd AS I1
INNER JOIN icd AS I2 
ON i2.primarycodetext = i1.primarycodetext
AND i2.primarycode <> I1.primarycode
WHERE I1.primarycode LIKE '%0'
```

But you are gonna have duplicates on your table after doing that. Thinking of what you really want to get (unique records for those values), then you should `DELETE` those records instead of updating them:

```
DELETE I1
FROM icd AS I1
INNER JOIN icd AS I2 
ON i2.primarycodetext = i1.primarycodetext
AND i2.primarycode <> I1.primarycode
WHERE I1.primarycode LIKE '%0'
```